# OAuth2 with Angular and reactive Spring Security

Tags: angular, typescript, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, spring-webflux

I am trying to implement a social login with [VK](https://vk.com) for my Angular app and Spring Webflux back end. At the moment I have an endpoint on back end to serve user info: `localhost:8080/people/me`. I tried to authenticate user on front end the following way:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get(USER_INFO_URL)
      .subscribe((resp: Response) => {
        if (resp.status < 300) {
          this.authenticated = true;
          resp.json()
            .then(vkUser => {
              let fields: [string, string] = ['firstName', vkUser.firstName];
              fields['lastName'] = vkUser.lastName;
              this.user = new User(vkUser.id, fields);
            });
        } else {
          window.location.href = AUTH_URL;
        }
      });
  }
```

However, when my Spring app redirects the client to `VK` for authentication, `VK` does not provide any `CORS` headers, causing the mechanism to fail.

Could someone please recommend a way of using `OAuth2` for Angular/Spring pair? I am using a `code` flow, so I guess first I need to get the code on front end and then send it to the Spring back end, so that it changes it for access token.

At the same time, I feel like my approach may be wrong and the entire auth process should take place at the back end, while front end should only get a cookie, but then I can't figure how to redirect AJAX request from front end to VK login page, handle that on back end and then return to Angular app.

Comment: does vk offer an oauth api? accomplishing the oauth flow requires some backend work, or configuration of a third party system, like fire base, to make requests to the vk authentication service you are using.

Comment: @Maus it does and it works perfectly if I try to access my back end endpoint directly from browser. It redirects me to VK, I grant permissions and Spring successfully authorizes me

Comment: can you do that same flow and then redirect back to your app with your session cookie set?

Comment: @Maus so you mean have a redirect uri set to back end resource and force users to access back end application first, which then will redirect them to front end with a cookie?

Comment: that seems like it would work. Is that acceptable given your site requirements?

Comment: @Maus i don't have particular requirements, so i will try that, thanks

Comment: I hope it's alright that I've summarized this conversation as an answer. If it ends up working for you, I think you could accept it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195081/discussion-between-maus-and-leonid-bor).

Comment: If my answer has prompted you to look into different problems in your implementation of the security flow, would you mind accepting it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not going to be possible without either configuring some third party software (that will enable cross origin requests from your website) or adding server side API code to your app that will accomplish the login process.

As we worked out in the comments, you already have successful login flow working in a couple of request cycles. You can use that same flow to get a valid session and then redirect onto your single page app. The cookie should be set as an HTTP only cookie (to prevent other JavaScript from hijacking it), but that will let you make requests against your server without adding additional authentication parameters successfully. You will have to check for that cookie when you service API requests, and write handling code that prompts the user to log in if the cookie is absent or no longer valid.

Hope that helps!

Comment: One last question: do you know if there's a standard way to do that in Spring or do I need to invent a wheel here?

Comment: in your question, what are you referring to with "that"?

Comment: To automatically redirect request to a particular address with a Set-Cookie header once authentication is done with OAuth2. Or will I need a custom controller and implement this logic manually?

Comment: seems pretty straightforward to me— whatever is view is routing people to the auth system, check there if the user has a valid session and then respond with a 302 sending them into your app.

Comment: i’m assuming whatever is currently happening with spring and your auth system causes that cookie to get set. I would not implement that yourself, but look for session utilities in spring, since you also need to be able to invalidate be cookie, and it involves crypto.